# Day not showing as right day in java

Tags: android, unix, epoch

I want to convert my unix time to an integer with this code:
http://pastebin.com/Q8XjiZab
But the problem is it returns 7 but it needs to return 1 for monday in my case.
How can I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already fixed it.
I needed to change `c.setTime(date);` to `new SimpleDateFormat("EE").format(date);`